# how to set the path of MODULAR HOME on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, mojo

I'm seemingly new to the VS Code environment and I was tinkering about with Mojo. However, the Mojo extension can't find it's path and I can't understand how to set it. Please help.

I tried going to extensions setting and type
{     "mojo.modularHomePath": "/absolute/path/to/.modular"
}
because that's what it says on the details page of the extension. I'm not getting any result.

Comment: Hi Annabeth, Modular Home contains the Mojo SDK installation. If you want to set the path of  Modular Home, please firstly check the path of Mojo SDK you have installed.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the MODULAR_HOME.
This usually means that
"/absolute/path/to/.modular" -> "/home/($username)/.modular"

(Ubuntu case)

Answer (score 1):

The guys from modular are still polishing rough edges. Currently, they do not detect if you are using bash or ZSH, so this bit has to be done manually.

They already print this on the install screen, but in the case you closed it here is the snippet for bash (add your username):

```
USERNAME=your_username
BASHRC=$( [ -f "$HOME/.bash_profile" ] && echo "$HOME/.bash_profile" || echo "$HOME/.bashrc" )
echo 'export MODULAR_HOME="/home/$USERNAME/.modular"' >> "$BASHRC"
echo 'export PATH="/home/$USERNAME/.modular/pkg/packages.modular.com_mojo/bin:$PATH"' >> "$BASHRC"
source "$BASHRC"
```

Then you can verify with

```
which mojo
/home/your_username/.modular/pkg/packages.modular.com_mojo/bin/mojo
```

And you can use mojo after restarting VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

> The extension will attempt to find the path of the Mojo SDK installation using the MODULAR_HOME environment variable.

Before installing Mojo extension on VS Code, have you installed Mojo SDK ?
If you have not installed [Mojo SDK](https://docs.modular.com/mojo/manual/get-started/), please install it. Then set the `MODULAR_HOME` environment in your OS stystem.

ubuntu

```
export MODULAR_HOME=/path/Mojo SDK installation
```

If MODULAR_HOME is not set within the environment, the path can be explicitly set via the mojo.modularHomePath extension setting.

> `mojo.modularHomePath` is the path to the `MODULAR_HOME` containing the Mojo SDK installation.

```
{
  "mojo.modularHomePath":"/path/Mojo SDK installation."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/home/($username)/.modular/pkg/packages.modular.com_mojo

I found it from:

> $ modular install mojo

> ```
> # Found release for https://packages.modular.com/mojo @ 0.5.0
> # Installing to /home/($username)/.modular/pkg/packages.modular.com_mojo
> # Downloading artifacts. Please wait...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In macosx use in your terminal

> echo $MODULAR_HOME

it will give you the path that is required to add in the VSCode Mojo Extension settings.
Most probably it will be a location like the following, depending on your installation.

> /Users/{username}/.modular

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).